# Response undefined for 302 status axios

Tags: ajax, typescript, axios, identityserver4

I am using axios with typescript.

I have a simple axios interceptor coded as below.

```
// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use((response: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
  // Do something with response data
  return response;
}, (error: any) => {
  // Do something with response error
  // Here "error.response" is undefined. 
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

What i am trying to do is I need to redirect to other location (identityserver SSO page but that is not relevant here I guess) when not authenticated.

so when calling my API returns 302 status code when not authenticated with proper location.

but that axios is not redirecting to that location automatically.

That is still ok if I have to manually redirect.

but I am getting "error.response" as undefined.

so now how do I redirect? Because I am not able to detect status code due to "error.response" as undefined.

In network tab it displays as following.

[image]

Response tab shows following. No response data available...!!!

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(error)`?

Comment: Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:87)

Comment: So `console.dir(error)`, open properties and try to find the status there

Comment: I did that, it isn't working.

Answer (score 5):

As I understood 302 code is handled by browser. After answer 302 browser will receive page that was passed by location header, and pass it to Axios. So you can find page html in `response.data`. Also in `response.request.responseURL` you can find URL you need to redirect to.

So I made something like this:

```
axios.post('.', Data)
     .then(response => {
         if (response.status === 200) {
             window.location.href = response.request.responseURL;
         }
     })
     .catch(error => {console.log(error)});
```

It is usefull for me now.

Comment: it doesn't work in IE11